# Android app webview ajax not working on checkout page opencart

Tags: android, ajax, android-studio, webview, opencart2.3

I'm currently working on simple android app webview. My website is opencart version 2.3.0.2 with default template. Web is working fine using browser for all devices tested desktop, mobile, tab. And on android also work fine except for checkout page (6 step). Its like not clickable and the tab not opening its content. I guess its because ajax/jquery on that page having conflict with android. Anyone having this experience? Mind to share where/what to fix to get it work?

This what i've in MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }
}
```

Comment: any help guys? suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding

```
setDomStorageEnabled(true)
```

in `MainActivity.java`.